# Change SKU number of product for returning clients in thankyou hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, I am trying to change a product SKU of an order received by a returning client. 
Currently I use the current code but it does not seem to work.

I have 2 different products. The product with id **`5836`** is a normal product while the other is a subscription.

This is my code:

```
function action_woocommerce_thankyou( $order_id ) {  
    // Let's get the order details
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Customer who made the purchase
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

    // Now get order count for the customer
    $order_count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];


        if ( $order_count > 1) {

            // Returning customer...
            if ( $product_id == '5836') {
            update_post_meta( $order_id['product_id'],  '_sku', $ANT0001 );}
            else {

            // Returning customer...
            update_post_meta( $order_id['product_id'],  '_sku', $ANT0002 );}


        } else {

            // New customer...

        }

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hi, I am the last 2 days really sick in bed. I hope soon I will get better and be able to test it. Thanks so much for your answer. I just need to make sure that it changes only the current order SKU and not the woocommerce products SKUs. Before I had the problem that it was messing with the products SKU and not the order SKU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update *(related to your comment)*:**  First concerning **SKU(s) item(s) in the order**, is not possible to update the SKU in the order, as there is no related data for any **`item ID`** concerning SKU in the related database table **`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`**. The related SKU(s) data is taken from product(s) directly.

---

I have tested your code and it works globally.

**what that doesn't work is**:

```
update_post_meta( $order_id['product_id'],  '_sku', $ANT0001 );
// and
update_post_meta( $order_id['product_id'],  '_sku', $ANT0001 );
```

because you are using **undefined variables `$ANT0001` and `$ANT0002`**.  Instead you should use this:

```
update_post_meta( $product_id,  '_sku', 'ANT0001' );
// and
update_post_meta( $product_id,  '_sku', 'ANT0001' );
```

or you should define your 2 variables **`$ANT0001`** and **`$ANT0002`**, and it will work, just as expected.

> **Don't forget that normally sku reference number has to be unique for each product**.